# miren este codigo donde podria tener el error

Tags: php

buenas noches quiero llamar imagenes de mi bd a un formulario de consulta, ya tengo el formulario de ingreso, guardar, eliminar y tabla, este es mi formulario que tengo de consulta con el que quiero llamar la imagenes de mi bd me podrian decir donde puede estar el error gracias

```
    <?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "especies forestales";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Conexión fallida: ".$conn->connect_error);
      }
 
     
    $salida = "";


    $query = "SELECT * FROM reconocimiento_especies WHERE nombre_comun LIKE '' ORDER By id_arbol LIMIT 25";

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {$check = @getimagesize($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);{$check = @getimagesize($_FILES['imaginex_hoja']['tmp_name']);  
    $carpeta_destino = 'imagenes plantas arregladas/';
    $archivo_subido = $carpeta_destino .$_FILES['foto']['name']; move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $archivo_subido);
   $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reconocimiento_especies (img, imaginex_hoja) VALUES (:img, :imaginex_hoja)");
   $statement->execute(array(':titulo' => $_POST['titulo'], ':imaginex_hoja'=> $_FILES['imaginex_hoja']['name'] ));


    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
        $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM reconocimiento_especies WHERE id_arbol LIKE '%$q%' OR nombre_comun LIKE '%$q%' OR nombre_cientifico LIKE '%$q%' OR tallo_raiz LIKE '%$q%' OR hoja LIKE '%$q%'OR img LIKE '%$q%'OR imaginex_hoja LIKE '%$q%'OR usos LIKE '$q' ";

    }

    $resultado = $conn->query($query);      
   

    if ($resultado->num_rows>0) {
        $salida.="<table border=1 class='tabla_datos'>
                <thead>
                    <tr id='arbol'>
                        <td>'nombre_comun'</td>
                        <td>nombre_cientifico</td>
                        <td>tallo_raiz</td>
                        <td>hoja</td>
                        <td>usos</td>
                        <td>img</td>
                        <td>imaginex_hoja</td>

                    </tr>

                </thead>
            
        <tbody>";

        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            $salida.="<tr>
                        <td>".$fila['nombre_comun']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['nombre_cientifico']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['tallo_raiz']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['hoja']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['usos']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['img']."</td>
      
                        </tr>";


        }
        $salida.="</tbody></table>";
    }else{
        $salida.="AUN NO HAZ DIGITADO NADA :(";
    }

    echo $salida;

    $conn->close();

 
?>
```

Comment: Saludos. Ya que no aportas mensaje de error, lo que obtienes e indicando lo que debes obtener; te comento lo siguiente; ¿que tienes en `$fila['img']` ? por que si es la ruta (relativa/absoluta) de la imagen debes ponerlo en el tag `img` ahora que si es como tal el archivo imagen deberás ponerlo de tal forma que en un `img` lo puedas mostrar.

Comment: hola robert gracias por comentar tan rapido el error que me muestra es este   PARSE ERROR: SYNTAX ERROR, UNEXPECTED END OF FILE IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\BUSCADORES -\BUSCAR.PHP ON LINE 79 me dice que es error cerrar php  eso es lo que me desconcierta y ahi estoy perdido

Comment: hola beta gracias por responder tan rapido este es el eror que me aparece PARSE ERROR: SYNTAX ERROR, UNEXPECTED END OF FILE IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\BUSCADORES -\BUSCAR.PHP ON LINE 79 lo que entiendo es que es error que cierre php por eso acudi a ustedes

Comment: beta es la ultima  donde cierro php ?> pues por eso estoy perdido no se porque me aparece ese error por eso acudo a ustedes que son muy buenos en esto

Answer (score 0):

Ese nombre de la base de datos lo puedes mejorar en una sola palabra o únelo, no lo dejes tan largo y con ese espacio de por medio.

El nombre de tu carpeta donde guardas las imágenes está compuesto por tres palabras separadas con espacios, ponle guiones o usa una sola palabra relacionada a lo que contendrá, es muy extenso.

Simplifica esos detalles, hazlo escueto.

Comment: rudy gracias por comentar tan pronto este es el error que me muestra PARSE ERROR: SYNTAX ERROR, UNEXPECTED END OF FILE IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\BUSCADORES -\BUSCAR.PHP ON LINE 79 lo que entiendo es que es erorr cerrar php

Comment: Bueno... veo que falta cerrar dos llaves en: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {$check = @getimagesize($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])};{$check = @getimagesize($_FILES['imaginex_hoja']['tmp_name'])};  Solo estas colocando llaves de apertura. Estas: {$check = @getimagesize($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])   ....}   <= esa;

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: gracias rvera  y rudy por ayudarme, las llaves que me dejaron solucionaron esa parte pero me sigue sin llamar la imagen en la consulta

Comment: Modifica el nombre de tu carpeta de imágenes ya que lo tienes con un nombre de tres palabras separadas por espacios, tu lo tienes así:  'imagenes plantas arregladas/'; déjalo algo así: 'img_plantas_arregladas/'; o también: 'imgPlantasArregladas/'; al final tu código debe de quedar algo así: $carpeta_destino = 'imgPlantasArregladas/'; si dejas esos espacios, te dará problemas ya que no se encontrará esa carpeta. Puedes checar el código de tu proyecto al dar click derecho y seleccionar ver código fuentes de la página y te vas donde aparecen las líneas de la imagen para que chequees si está bien.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el if que tienes en la línea 19:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {$check = @getimagesize($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);{$check = @getimagesize($_FILES['imaginex_hoja']['tmp_name']);
```

No estás cerrándolo en ningún lado.

Te recomiendo que uses algún editor propio de PHP o alguna herramienta tipo linter

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente el error `UNEXPECTED END OF FILE` se da cuando hay un error de sintaxis en el que faltó colocar algún `;` o cerrar algún paréntesis, entonces como hay algo "sin terminar" php asume que al archivo le falta algo. (puede pasar también cuando el archivo en efecto está incompleto por alguna subida de archivo fallida por ejemplo).

En el trozo de código que compartes (sin entrar a discutir algunos otros detalles mejorables) hay un problema con los paréntesis. la siguiente línea (la separé para mejorar la lectura):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {
    $check = @getimagesize($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);
    {$check = @getimagesize($_FILES['imaginex_hoja'['tmp_name']);
```

Debería transformarse en algo como:

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {
        $check = @getimagesize($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);
        $check = @getimagesize($_FILES['imaginex_hoja']['tmp_name']);
    }
```

Eso ya debería solucionar el problema sobre el que preguntas. Los mensajes de error suelen ser bastante explicativos. En este caso, un error de **sintaxis** de tipo **UNEXPECTED END OF FILE** en la línea **79** te da gran parte de la información que necesitas al menos para indagar de forma más precisa el error.

Comment: Creo que el cierre debería ser un poco más abajo, después de mover el archivo y ejecutar la consulta para insertar.

Comment: gracias rvera y rudy por ayudarme pero me sigue sin llamar imagenes a mi consulta  como lo debo hacer me podrian orientar

Comment: NOTICE: UNDEFINED INDEX: FOTO IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\BUSCADORES -\BUSCAR.PHP ON LINE 23
NOTICE: TRYING TO ACCESS ARRAY OFFSET ON VALUE OF TYPE NULL IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\BUSCADORES -\BUSCAR.PHP ON LINE 23
NOTICE: UNDEFINED INDEX: IMG IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\BUSCADORES -\BUSCAR.PHP ON LINE 23

NOTICE: TRYING TO ACCESS ARRAY OFFSET ON VALUE OF TYPE NULL IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\BUSCADORES -\BUSCAR.PHP ON LINE 23
FATAL ERROR: UNCAUGHT ERROR: CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION EXECUTE() ON BOOL IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\BUSCADORES -\BUSCAR.PHP:25 STACK TRACE: #0 {MAIN} THROWN IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\BUSCADORES -\BUSCAR.PHP LINE 25

Comment: Triby tiene razón, puede que haya que cerrar más abajo el paréntesis, solo me fijé en el error sintáctico. no en lo funcional.
Respecto del error Jeremy, dice que en la linea 23 (no sabemos cual es) estás tratando de acceder a una posición de un array en una variable nula. No es posible deducirlo con el código que compartiste pero imagino que debes revisar con cuidado los nombres de los inputs de tipo `file` porque veo varios nombres distintos y puede que estés intentando usar uno que no existe para tu consulta de BD.